# UIAlertView pops up twice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I am trying to use two UIAlertViews but both pop up when i trigger one.

```
-(IBAction)continueGame_button:(id)sender {
    //=====CHECK IF THERE IS AN ON-GOING GAME, IF SO CONTINUE=====//
    AccessCurrentGameData *isThereAnOngoingGameFunction = [AccessCurrentGameData new];
    BOOL ongoingGame = [isThereAnOngoingGameFunction checkIfGameOngoing];
    [isThereAnOngoingGameFunction release];
    NSLog(@"+ + +continueGame_button+ + +");
    NSLog(@"ongoingGame = %@\n", (ongoingGame ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

    if (ongoingGame == YES) {
        NSLog(@"+++++++++ ONGOING GAME +++++++++");

        myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fortsätta spel" 
                                             message:@"Det finns ett aktivt spel, klicka Spela eller Tillbaka"
                                            delegate:self
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Tillbaka"
                                   otherButtonTitles:@"Spela", nil];
        myAlert.tag=kTagContinueGame;
        [myAlert show];
        [myAlert release];
    }
}


-(IBAction)newGame_button:(id)sender {
    myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Varning" 
                                         message:@"Om du går vidare kommer pågående spel stoppas och nollställas!"
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Tillbaka"
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Fortsätt", nil];
    myAlert.tag=kTagNewGame;
    [myAlert show];
    myAlert release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    switch(myAlert.tag ) {
        case kTagContinueGame:
            NSLog(@"kTagContinueGame");
            break;
        case kTagNewGame:
            NSLog(@"kTagNewGame");
            AccessCurrentGameData *zeroCurrentGameFileFunction = [AccessCurrentGameData new];
            [zeroCurrentGameFileFunction firstCreationOrRestoreOfGameDataFile];
            [zeroCurrentGameFileFunction release];

            NewGameViewController * temp = [[NewGameViewController alloc] init];
            [self setNewGameViewController:temp];
            [temp release];
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newGameViewController animated:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For which action is the `continueGame_button:(id)sender` method being called?  Please post what you wired it as in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your IBOutlet. You may have 1 button that is connected to 2 of your IBAction's.

If it's a UIButton, check the `touchUpInside`.

[image]